# Find the parent or independent key in array

Tags: php

```
Array = ( "a" => "b", 
          "b" => "c", 
          "c" => "y", 
          "d" => "z"
         );

Output: c and d
```

Please give me idea on how to loop an array that will find their last parent link. Its hard to describe the problem but please see the expected output.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: whats the logic here?

Comment: that's is what i'm looking for..it will be used for monitoring..

Comment: What is unique with 'c' and 'd'? You have not explained why they are given as output.

Comment: e.g. usage will be used in monitoring. PC 1 is down, PC 1 is connected to SW 1, SW 1 is connected to R 1..if all is down, report all but to lessen the report only their up-line will be reported which is R 1.

Comment: That's an output of y and z, then isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want is a function that will return all keys with a value that isn't in the keys of the array. You can use the `array_keys()` function for that ([docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)) and `in_array()` ([docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)).

```
function independantKeys( $arr ) {
  $output = Array();

  $keys = array_keys( $arr );

  foreach( $arr as $key => $val ) {
    if( !in_array( $val, $keys ) ) {
      $output[] = $key;
    }
  }

  return $output;
}
```